# Make PHP include randomizer not repeat itself

Tags: php, javascript, random, include, server-side-includes

### Situation

I have a relatively short php code I found and tweaked that includes a random html file from my 'randomizer' folder into my page.

Here is the code

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);
  function random_file($string){
    return ((file_exists($string))&&(preg_match('#(\.html)$#i',$string)))  ? true : false ;
  }

  define('OUTPUT_TYPE','text');

  define('RANDOM_FILES_FOLDER','randomizer/');

  $my_array = Array();
  $my_dir = RANDOM_FILES_FOLDER ;

  if ($dir = @opendir("$my_dir")) {

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != ".."  && !is_dir($my_dir.$file))
      {
        switch(OUTPUT_TYPE):

          case'text':
            if(random_file($my_dir.$file)){
              $my_array[] = $file;
            }
          break;

          default:
          break;

        endswitch;

      }
    }
    closedir($dir);
  }

  if(count($my_array)>0){

    $random_number = rand(0, count($my_array)-1);
    $random_file = $my_array[$random_number];

    switch(OUTPUT_TYPE):

      case'text':
        include($my_dir.$random_file);
      break;

      default:
      break;

    endswitch;

  }
?>
```

### Question

It does what it is supposed to do (perhaps someone can trim/optimize that code for me) but I have only a few files to randomize and I don't want the same file to appear twice when I refresh or open the page a day after.

I think cookies may be the answer, but not sure how to do anything with them.

Can anyone write a piece code to add to mine to do that or provide a code that has all those attributes? keep in mind it must include files at random from a folder, I don't want the code from those files on my actual page code for CMS purposes

*Keep in mind I am a PHP and Javascript beginner with VERY basic knowledge, so please dumb it down for me.*

Thanks!

Comment: So you basically want us to develop the functionality for you? My rate is 40€/hour... ;)

Comment: Do you just want the next access show different?

Comment: @Martin I tried it myself and failed :( .  I will gladly develop short snippets of code in HTML5 or CCS3 for you, or even do a small PSD or SWF file if you need it :)

Comment: What happens when I access your site more times in a day than there are files in your directory?

Comment: @Martin it should start over the counting and repeat the files, but only once it has gone through all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very rough:

```
session_start();
$dir = 'randomizer/';

if (empty($_SESSION['files'])) {
    $_SESSION['files'] = array_filter(scandir($dir), function ($file) use ($dir) {
        return is_file($dir . $file) && preg_match('#(\.html)$#i', $file);
    });
    shuffle($_SESSION['files']);
}

include $dir . array_shift($_SESSION['files']);
```

Keep a list of all candidate files in the session, use them one by one. That way all files will be displayed once in random order before the cycle starts again. Only not recommended if the list is *very* long.

It's worth noting that the `array_filter` callback syntax requires PHP 5.3.

Comment: Would this work if I close and re-open my browser? I though sessions were only good while browser is open.

Comment: @amesguich That depends on how you configure your sessions. Sessions work with cookies, so any cookie solution has the same problem. If a cookie has no explicit expiration date, it'll be thrown away very quickly. If you set the expiration date longer, it'll stay.

Comment: Follow-up question. How do I make that session stick for a week regardless of closing browser in-between?

Comment: Thanks deceze, that works for sessions, now the issue, like the other answer I get a syntax error and my page doesn't work. I just checked and I do have PHP 5.3 running.

Comment: You have to tell what the error is and what line it points to. It's pretty much impossible to help otherwise.

Comment: @Juhana it's line 5 and 7 of that code and it just says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /index.php on lines 46, 48"

Comment: @ame That's an error in **your** code, mine doesn't have an `if`.

Comment: @deceze No, it's highlighting your lines. I'm just putting your code alone inside <?php ?> and its highlighting rows 5 and 7 of your code. the row that says `$_SESSION['files'] = array_filter(scandir($dir), function ($file) use ($dir) {` and the one that says `});`

Comment: @deceze the server gives me the following output: Warning: include(test1.html) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/PMWC/index.php on line 11

Warning: include(test1.html) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public_html/PMWC/index.php on line 11

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'test1.html' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php53/lib/php') in /public_html/PMWC/index.php on line 11

Comment: @ame OK, that one was because of the missing `$dir` for the include, fixed that. But a) you should really learn to debug and fix simple errors like this yourself and b) that's a completely different error from the `unexpected T_IF` you quoted before.

Comment: @deceze I'm learning slowly, sorry for bugging you so much, that worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect way to do this but it will work(intentionally simple):
Include this after the line `$random_file = $my_array[$random_number];`

```
$oldFile = ''
if(!empty($_COOKIE['oldfilename']) {
    $oldFile = $_COOKIE['oldfilename'];
}
while ($oldFile == $random_file) {
    $random_number = rand(0, count($my_array)-1);
    $random_file = $my_array[$random_number];
}
setcookie('oldfilename', $random_file);
```

Comment: There's a ')' missing before '{'. Since I wasn't typing this in an IDE, parenthesis matching or quote matching can be inaccurate. But if you want to work in PHP you should be able to work out syntax issues like these.

Comment: Thought that was the issue, I caught it and it's the first thing I tried, but I still get the same error

Comment: I just tried it, I don't get any syntax error. Could you paste your output?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /index.php on line 58     (Where line 58 is line 2 of your code modification)

Comment: I just noticed, there's a ';' missing after $oldFile = ''. As I mentioned earlier I cannot be sure about the syntax errors, I am not used to writing code without syntax highlighting and error notifications(yeah I am spoiled)